# How to register Service in LINUX using installAnywhere

Tags: service, installanywhere

I have Register windows NT Service using Register windows Service action using installAnywhere.

I want the same with LINUX.
I wanted  to Register Service in Linux environment but could  not found action regarding.

Any thoughts to register service in Linux using installAnywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a "standard" startup process in the Unix / Linux world is the [AT&T System V init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) (Wikipedia) approach. This "standard" was created on AT&T's System V many years ago, then variations of it were implemented in most common Unix and Linux variants.

This approach involves creating links, based on run levels, under the `/etc` directory. Some distributions took slightly different approaches to this than the original AT&T System V approach (see the article referenced above).

Over the past few years this has become a trickier proposition. There's a trend among Unix and Linux distributions to abandon SysV init for new approaches that address some of the shortcomings of the SysV init way (again, see the article referenced above).

In InstallAnywhere, there is no canned "Create Unix System Service" Action. So, it falls to the installation engineer to roll his own. If you're targeting only one Unix/Linux platform, it's relatively easy: write and install scripts and configuration files, and create links, that meet the standard approach for your distribution (e.g., systemd, Upstart, launchd, SMF, etc.). For us, we do most of this work in scripts that are embedded in Execute Batch or Shell Script Actions.

If you are targeting different platforms, then you need to determine at installation time what platform, and in some cases what version of the platform, you are currently running on. After that you need to execute the proper installation steps for the current platform.

We do this by creating Group Actions, with platform-specific rules applied, that encapsulate the steps needed for the platforms we support. In a last-ditch effort, we default to the "standard" AT&T SysV approach, installing scripts and creating the links needed to enable our application to start in our supported run levels.

Also related to this topic is the use of frameworks that ease the burden of creating Unix/Linux system services. These include: [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp), [Yet Another Java Service Wrapper](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/), [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/), as well as others.
I suggest that you get the scripts working and tested outside of InstallAnywhere, then create the InstallAnywhere Group Actions and Execute Batch or Shell Script Actions needed to configure your system services during installation. It's a tedious process, but getting each platform working outside of InstallAnywhere, then implementing that platform inside of InstallAnywhere will save you time in the long run. On the upside, once you get it configured and working, you should not have to change this part of your installer for some time to come.

Another approach we are considering, but have not yet moved to, is to use a single, top-level script that does the heavy lifting for us. We'll adopt a standard naming convention and directory structure tied to platform names. During installation we copy an entire directory structure of installation scripts for all our supported platforms. At the top of that structure is a single script that knows how to sniff the current platform and execute the proper script for that platform. If the user has elected to enable our application as a system service, we will execute this one script during installation. At the end of the installation, we will delete the installation scripts directory.

This will reduce the complexity of our installer and allow us to add support for more platforms without changing the installer. If you support multiple platforms, you may wish to start with this approach. It may save you time in the long-run if you expect to add support for more platforms in the future.